# MPAndroidChart - How I can avoid the "-0" value representation

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I have some entry's with 0 value, but in my YAxis this is representing with "-0" value. 
How I can avoid or exclude this?

Comment: Which type of chart you are using?

Comment: The type is Line chart

Comment: YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft(); leftAxis.setStartAtZero(true)

Comment: But I want to draw negative values. So I can't start in zero

Answer (score 0):

Use `YAxisValueFormatter`, format everything that is >= 0 to positive by using `Math.abs(...)`

Documentation of the [YAxisValueFormatter](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-YAxisValueFormatter-interface).

---

```
private class AxisValueFormatter implements YAxisValueFormatter{
        private DecimalFormat mFormat;

        public AxisValueFormatter() {
            mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0");
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis) {
            if(Float.compare(-0.0f, value) == 0){
                value = Math.abs(value);
            }
            return mFormat.format(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This not avoid the -0, when I zoom in the chart. Do you have any idea?